# Data from mysql database in a JList

Tags: java, mysql

I am still relatively unfamiliar with Java and would like to have help with the following problem:

On my JFrame I have a Jbutton (SubmitBtn) and a JList (List), how can I select the data from my database into the JList?

Here is my code:

```
    SubmitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             try {
                 Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eindopdrachtnamen", "root", "" );
             //make connection with jdbc with the name myConn

                 String str=text1.getText();
                 String str2=text2.getText();
                 Statement s = (Statement) myConn.createStatement();
                 s.execute("insert into namen (Voornaam, Achternaam)values('" + str + "','" + str2 + "')");
                 //add data to database with Textfields


                    }


            catch(Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();  
            }





        };
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried executing a query, and iterating through a resultset? Have you tried creating a JList or a ListModel?

Comment: I have created a JList in my JFrame and tried to connect with a SQL statement (select * from "my database") with the JList in the button code, but it does not work, so I have deleted that.